# JProgressBar won't update

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I'm trying the code I found on the voted answer from this question: [Download file using java apache commons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698534/download-file-using-java-apache-commons)

It's a download application, take a little look, (I'm not much familiar with JFrames and ActionEvents)

Download.java

```
package main;

public class Download extends JFrame implements Runnable{

    public static int total;
    public static int done;

    private static class ProgressListener implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            done = (int)((DownloadCountingOutputStream) e.getSource()).getByteCount();
            jbar.repaint();
            DownloadCountingOutputStream.parent.draw((int)((DownloadCountingOutputStream) e.getSource()).getByteCount());//redraw
            DownloadCountingOutputStream.parent.repaint();
        }
    }

    public static JProgressBar jbar = new JProgressBar(); 



    public void draw(int downloaded){System.out.println("downloaded: "+downloaded+ " Total: "+total);

        if (downloaded== 0){

        Container cont = new Container();       
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setSize(600, 450);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);

        cont.add(jbar);     
        jbar.setBounds(40, 50, 500, 50);                
        jbar.setMaximum(total);//The total value of bytes to download
        //jbar.setValue(50);
        add(cont);

        jbar.setVisible(true);  
        }

        jbar.setValue(downloaded);      
            //This should update the value of the progress Bar
    }

    public void run() {


        URL dl = null;
        File fl = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        ProgressListener progressListener = new ProgressListener();

        draw(done);

        try {
            fl = new File(System.getProperty("user.home").replace("\\", "/") + "/Desktop/afile.rar");
            dl = new URL("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/48076798/afile.rar");
            os = new FileOutputStream(fl);
            is = dl.openStream();

            total = Integer.parseInt(dl.openConnection().getHeaderField("Content-Length"));

            String total = dl.openConnection().getHeaderField("Content-Length");

            DownloadCountingOutputStream dcount = new DownloadCountingOutputStream(os);
            dcount.setListener(progressListener);
            dcount.setParent(this);

            IOUtils.copy(is, dcount);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (os != null) { 
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
            if (is != null) { 
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

DownloadCountingOutputStream.java

```
package main;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.output.CountingOutputStream;

public class DownloadCountingOutputStream extends CountingOutputStream {

    private ActionListener listener = null;
    public static Download parent;

    public DownloadCountingOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public void setListener(ActionListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void setParent(Download o){

        parent = o;
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterWrite(int n) throws IOException {
        super.afterWrite(n);
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, 0, null));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're making Swing calls off of the Swing event thread and don't appear to be respecting Swing's threading rules. Consider using a SwingWorker for your background work and updating the worker's progress property as the Swing progress and SwingWorker tutorials show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from the code sample you've provide...

The main cause of this problem is trying to update the UI while blocking from the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT).

It's important to NEVER do any long running or blocking operations within the EDT as this will prevent repaint requests from been acted upon.

For more information have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

The example below demonstrates the use of a `SwingWorker` that provides progress updates that are re-synced with the UI

```
public class TestProgress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestProgress();
    }

    public TestProgress() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ProgressPane progressPane = new ProgressPane();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(progressPane);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                progressPane.doWork();
            }
        });
    }

    public class ProgressPane extends JPanel {

        private JProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            progressBar = new JProgressBar();

            add(progressBar);

        }

        public void doWork() {

            Worker worker = new Worker();
            worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        progressBar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            });

            worker.execute();

        }
    }

    public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
                int progress = Math.round(((float) index / 1000f) * 100f);
                setProgress(progress);

                Thread.sleep(10);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```