# JProgressBar doesn't update during download

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jbutton, jprogressbar

Using a swing button, I'm trying to download an html file and write it to a new html file, while doing a progress bar. When I click the button, my program seems to freeze until the download finishes, and then the progress bar is suddenly 100%. I'm not quite sure how to fix this problem as I am new to java.

```
private void jButton2MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    try {    
        URL oracle = new URL("http://mywebsite.com");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String input_path = "d:/website/updatedsite.html";
        WriteFile data = new WriteFile(input_path, false);
        int length = yc.getContentLength();
        int current = 0;
        jProgressBar1.setMaximum(length);
        jProgressBar1.setValue(0);
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            data.writeToFile(inputLine);
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                jProgressBar1.setValue(i);
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e) { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame1.this, "Error " + e.getMessage());
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [JProgressBar won't update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094666/jprogressbar-wont-update)

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're both downloading and updating the progress bar in the same thread - that's why the gui gets actually updated AFTER the download is finished.

Use a separate worker thread for downloading  like explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a `SwingWorker`. It's made for problems such as this. Here is a snippet from some code from my codebase that uses an indeterminate progress bar, but it'll help give you a general idea of what to do (`vui` is a JFrame):

```
vui.clearOutput();
vui.setOutput("Waiting for items to copy...\n"
            + "This could take several minutes. Please standby...");
vui.disableExit();
vui.disableInput();
vui.disableNext();
vui.showProgressBar();

// make thread so you can disable all options when zipping and enable progress bar
SwingWorker transferWorker = new SwingWorker() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("resources/bin/transferCopier.bat");

            StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
            StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");
            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();

            p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VaderController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Logger.getLogger(VaderController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ie);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void done() {
        vui.hideProgressBar();
        vui.clearOutput();
        vui.setOutput("Transfer Complete!\n\n"
                    + "Push \"Exit\" to quit.\n\n");
        vui.enableExit();
        mode = VaderMode.END;
    }
};
transferWorker.execute();
```

When `transferWorker.execute();` is performed, `doInBackground()` is invoked. Once `doInBackground()` is done doing its computations, `done()` is then invoked. `done()` is where you would do any final updates to the GUI.

The key things to note about my code above is that I enable the progress bar before executing the `SwingWorker` then when the `SwingWorker` is done executing, I disable the progress bar.

Resources:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html