# Access on http authentication secured image in all browsers with Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-authentication

I have the following problem:
I want to access a picutre (Motion Stream on Raspberry Pi) which is secured by http authentication.

To don't show the password in plain html code, I use this in html:

```
<img src="/image"/>
```

And process the request on my Spring Boot server, so this function in my WebController class redirects the request to the real location of the image:

```
    @RequestMapping("/image")
    public RedirectView image() {
        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
        redirectView.setUrl("http://user:password@server:port/");
        return redirectView;
    }
```

This method works fine in Firefox, but I can't access the image in Chromium unless I enter the login data in a new tab by accessing the server myself. How can I create a working and even safer method for all browsers, on backend with Java & Spring or frontend with html & Javascript?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using basic authentication and Spring Security? That would be really easy with Security.

Comment: I'm using the Spring Security LDAP Module for basic authentication. Its just a private single-user web application, so it might be ok. The image is loaded from another server (on same device) running by motion with http authentication.

Comment: You can fetch the image in the back end and return a byte array from your endpoint. Your img src would be the url of the endpoint. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080207/how-to-download-image-using-rest-template